# Можно ли в rabbitmq сделать какие-то периодические задачи?

Tags: rabbitmq

Например, каждый час добавляет одно и тоже сообщение в заданную очередь или эксчендж? без крона

Answer (score 0):

Нет. RabbitMQ это именно "очередь", а не планировщик.

Answer (score 0):

Силами самого RabbitMQ такого сделать пока нельзя, но если вы пишете на asp.net core и используете MassTransit c RabbitMQ в качестве транспорта, то вы можете подключить планировщик Quartz и легко отправлять сообщения в брокер из любого своего сервиса:

https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/